# Samsung Galaxy GT-s7562 rooting using (Arch)linux

Tags: linux, samsung, odin, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy Trend II Duos (GT-S7562) bought from China.(I live in Ireland) Hence, I am not able to access any google services through apps (no access to Play Store, Google based apps).

I guess I have to root my phone and maybe install a custom ROM. However, I see that most of the guides on websites are for windows machines and need Samsung kies/drivers. However, I use Arch-Linux as my only OS for Computer. I can connect my android phone using MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)

Q1) Do I need to install Samsung driver/Kies on my linux machine. If yes, then how?

Q2) Can I install custom ROMs meant for other countries on my phone?

Q3) How should I do all these on Linux? (which does not have odin and other popular tools)

Sincerely,
Android Newbie

Model Number: GT-S7562
Andorid Version: 4.0.4
Baseband version: S7562ZCMH1
Kernel version: 3.0.8-1219573
Build number: IMM761.S7562ZCAMH!

Answer (score -1):

see http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=49779385#post49779385

You first need to update your Baseband (modem) to the right locale. Then you can install corresponding ROMs.